# Dynamically loading an array into script tags

Tags: ajax

I am currently using a [full-screen image slider called supersized](http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) on a site, which references the images and associated extras in a script tag like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        $.supersized({

            // Functionality
            property_1   :   value,     
            property_2   :   value,     

            slides       :   [
            {image :'http://image1.jpg', title :'Name1', url :'1.html'},
            {image :'http://image2.jpg', title :'Name2', url :'2.html'},
            {image :'http://image3.jpg', title :'Name3', url :'3.html'},
            ],

            // Options             
            option_1     :   value,
            option_1     :   value
        });
    });
</script>
```

What would be very nice, is to be able to dynamically load a new array of images with their associated extras via ajax (jquery preferred, but vanilla js fine). Is this possible? If so, I've struggled to find any resources that explain how.

Comment: sure, just have your server-side script spit out an array of images in JSON format. jquery can trivially accept that and use it as any other javascript array.

Comment: I think I understand. I'm fine getting the API to generate the JSON, it's getting javascript to pull that data dynamically on an event.

Answer (score 1):

It seem that you need to code such feature youself.

See what plugin author is writing in FAQ: http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/faq.html#q-4

```
Can I load different sets of slides without reloading the page?
This is a feature I am looking to develop out in the future. If you're hurting for it in the meantime, you can hire me for custom work.
```

If you need just one set of slides loaded by AJAX you can code it like that:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $.ajax({
    url: "URL"
  }).done(function ( data ) {
    $.supersized({

        // Functionality
        property_1   :   value,     
        property_2   :   value,     

        slides       :  data.slides,

        // Options             
        option_1     :   value,
        option_1     :   value
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Interesting - I'll take a look at that option more closely. Thanks.